# I'm looking for a teen book trilogy with science fiction

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

This series is a trilogy.

It features a boy in the present who meets a girl from the future who has come to help him save the coral reefs/rain forests/arctic glaciers because they're in danger in the future. The future is apparently overrun with robots that wish to pollute the earth or something like that. There is a wizard-like guy in the book too.

I know that isn't much but it's all I remember. I do remember though the boy likes a girl in the present and in the end he has to choose between the two girls.

Comment: Any idea of the publish date?

Comment: THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH! I read this book back in middle school (I'm now a senior) and for some reason today, I just remembered it and felt like reading it but I forgot the name and this is like the only site that helped me, thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [The Caretaker Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Caretaker_Trilogy)?  There's a guy who has to save the oceans, rain forest, and polar ice caps.  He finds a wizard named Kidah.

> The story focuses on Jack Danielson, a teenager sent back from the future to save the world’s oceans. Whirlwind, the second book in the Caretaker Trilogy, tells the story of Jack’s efforts to save the Amazon rain forest; [...] In the rain forest Jack finds Eko and after some romantic scenes they find Kidah, a mysterious wizard lost in time, [...] in the final novel of the trilogy Jack has to save the polar ice caps.  He visits his own time, a world of burning deserts, and has to choose between his destiny as a prince of the future and his life as an ordinary present-day teenager.

Also, according to the [Cast of Characters](http://thecaretakertrilogy.com/cast-of-characters.asp) on The Caretaker Trilogy website, Jack has a girlfriend in the present and there's a girl from the future named Eko who helps train him to fight.

> P.J. PETERS: Jack’s true love, kidnapped by the Dark Lord to lure Jack into a trap. What will he endure to save her?
>
> EKO: Sexy sensei sent back in time, Eko gives Jack a big dose of tough love while training him to use his enhanced powers to fight the Dark Army.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, the OP says that a girl goes back in time, but in The Caretaker Trilogy a guy is sent back.

Comment: @elssar I think the "Eko" mentioned briefly in the wiki article is the girl from the future.